# Can't find the list of most (all?) tab names for the ribbon in Office

Tags: vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, ribbon, office-2013

After some heavy googling, I've concluded that I'm unable to locate information on the id names for the different components of the ribbon in Office.

For instance, even though the following XML works, I need to hide the add-in error display due to *TabMail* being at fault when a new email is being created. It's my understand that it's because I currently target **all** windows in Outlook but should be only targeting the main one. When a new email is being created, my add-in tries to insert itself in there too failing and complaining.

```xml
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabMail">
      <group id="Animals" label="Animal group">
        <splitButton id="MainSplitButton" size="large">
          <button id="Donkey"
                  label="Donkey me"
                  getImage="GetImage"
                  showImage="true"
                  onAction="Donkey_Click"/>
          ...
```

- Where can I find the list of all (or at least the most common) tab and group names?
- Or at least, what to google for (apparently my searches weren't based on words distinctive enough)?

While preferring the digital information, I'd be willing to purchase some literature covering Office add-in development. Even on that subject my search was inconclusive (many hits, no one of which feeling like the right stuff.)

Answer (score 4):

For Office 2007 see [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582), for Office 2010 Fluent UI [click here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) and the 2013 version is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798).

I also didn't find much good literature, but there is tons of posts on forums and since I work for Excel only (which has quite a good developer community) I settled with that.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I'll check that out. Generally, it's very difficult to fins info on ribbon, IMHO. For instance, I can't find a way to reference a checkbox (needs to be set to true programmatically). Very annoying...

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking documentation for using Ribbon callbacks here you go

For Office 2007

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

For Office 2010

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Am I to understand that Office 2013 is covered by the 2010 version?

Comment: I havent worked with Office 2013 but I believe the ribbon callbacks havent changed much.

Comment: Will try that out. At the moment I've learned to dislike Outlook so I'm hoping it'll get smoother soon. :)